# Accessing Azure Table from an Azure Function in PowerShell

Tags: function, azure, powershell, azure-table-storage

I've written an Azure Function in PowerShell and I'd like to make some queries to my Azure Table from this Function. I'm not sure how to authenticate.
How do i get my function to access my azure table ?

*Tried to leverage Managed Identity but did not go anywhere with it
*Same with Service Principal

*It works if i use connect-azuread but the function prompts me with a link and a machine code to authenticate

Thanks!
David

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell

Comment: yes, I did.There's no reference to authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Azure Function, if you enable the Identity and assign the role assignment for it. And then it will already have the permission according to the assignment if you create the PowerShell script and run it. So you do not need to authenticate for the Managed Identity. You just need to assign the permission to the MSI.

You can check it through the command like this:

```
$context = Get-AzContext
$context.Account
```

Then you can see the output shows like this:

[image]